# Decoupling Sizzle.js from jQuery, and replacing it with Sel.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, sizzle

I recently came across [Sel.js](https://github.com/amccollum/sel) which, among other things, supports the [Draft CSS Level 4 Selectors](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#overview) (such as the [Subject selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) which lets you target the parent of a matched CSS node).

I would love to start playing with this library in combination with [jQuery](https://jquery.org/), and am curious if anyone has experience (or a good guess for how to accomplish) replacing the [Sizzle.js](http://sizzlejs.com/) selector library which jQuery is based on with a different selector library (in this case Sel.js).

Any ideas, or examples to look at on the web someplace for decoupling jQuery from Sizzle, and making it instead rely on a different selector engine?

Comment: This is where sizzle is connected to jQuery: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/sizzle-jquery.js you would just need to re-implement these with sel.js instead.

Comment: Hmm - ok - I'll start there and see what I can come up with on jsFiddle as an override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't necessarily a true *replacement*, per-se, but rather a fall-back. **Sizzle** will throw an error when encountering what it considers to be "invalid syntax", such as the CSS4 Subject Selector (`div! > .jquery-css4`, as an example).

```
> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div! > .jquery-css4
```

One solution is to `catch {}` those errors thrown by **Sizzle**, then attempt to fall back to **Sel.js** for selection instead, by overwriting the `$()` function as follows:

```
$ = function (selector, context) {
    try {
        return jQuery(selector, context);
    } catch (e) {
        return jQuery(sel.sel(selector, context));
    }
};
```

After overriding this way, you can then use:

```
$('div! > .jquery-css4');
```

...which will correctly return the `<div>` which contains a child of class `.jquery-css4`.

As an alternative, you could create a simple `css4` selection plugin, using something like:

```
$.css4 = function(selector, context) { 
    return $(sel.sel(selector, context));
};
```

At which point the above could be re-written:

```
$.css4('div! > .jquery-css4');
```

The benefit of this approach is that it does not rely on error-handling, and is more declarative. In essence - you should know when you're using a CSS4 selector, and need the added support, and when you aren't. However - both approaches are fairly non-intrusive.

For anyone using these methods, though, **please note**: I have not tested extensively with queries using the `context` parameter. It may not play nice with `Sel.js` - so if you need to take it to that further step, please be aware that you may need to enhance this code further.

Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/x3AtM/) showing the code in-action.